# What is $C^{-1}$v and how do I prove that $C^{-1}$v is an eigenvector of $C^{-1}AC$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $C$ be $n×n$ matrices, and let $C$ be invertible. Show that, if **v** is an eigenvector of A with corresponding eigenvalue $λ$, then $C^{-1}$**v** is an eigenvector of $C^{-1}AC$ with corresponding eigenvalue λ. Then show that all eigenvectors of $C^{-1}AC$ are of the form $C^{-1}$**v**, where **v** is an eigenvector of $A$.

I don´t know how to start here since it is much more abstract than what I have worked with before. Especially how do I get to $C^{-1}$**v**?

Comment: "Especially how do I get to $C^{-1}\mathbf v$?" You don't. In much the same way as one might work with $\sqrt 5$ in algebraic expressions instead of swapping it out with $2.24$, it is entirely fine to just keep $C^{-1}\mathbf v$ around in that form and not worry too much about trying to simplify it. Just like $\sqrt 5$ tells you "If you square me, you'll get exactly 5", $C^{-1}v$ tells you "if you multiply me with $C$, you'll get exactly $\mathbf v$".

Answer (score 1):

Note that $C^{-1}$**v** is actually a column vector. Now just compute the required multiplication:

$C^{-1}AC(C^{-1})v=C^{-1}Av=C^{-1}\lambda v=\lambda C^{-1}v$.

For the second part, since $C$ is invertible, notice that any vector $u$ can be written as $u=C^{-1}v$ for some $v$ a vector. Thus we have, in this form, assuming $u$ is a e.v.,

$C^{-1}ACu=C^{-1}Av=\mu u$ where $\mu$ is a eigenvalue this time. Some simple rearrangement should give the answer.

Comment: So am I right to understand that C^(-1)ACv=λv  -->  C^(-1) AC(C^(-1))v=C^(-1) λv --> C^(-1) Av=λC^(-1) v

Comment: @user1007532 That looks wrong you meant to multiply on the left for both sides